# How to connect Cloud Composer Airflow to Oracle database?

Tags: python, oracle, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to connect to an **oracle database** with a python job over **GCP airflow**.

Even though I tried this with both **OracleOperator** and **OracleHook**, I always get the same error.

You can see the error and my code below.
How can I resolve this error on GCP Cloud Composer?

Please note that I did not do these operations on my local computer.

Also, how can I print the result of a select query that I sent to the oracle database?
Thanks in advance.

***My Code:***

```
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.oracle_operator import OracleOperator

default_args = {
'owner': 'Airflow_Test',
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date':  days_ago(1),   
'email': ['Airflow_Test@Airflow_Test.com'],
'email_on_failure': True,
'email_on_retry': False,
'retries': 1,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

schedule_interval = "* * * * *"

dag_gtb = DAG(
    'Airflow_Test_Python_Job',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=schedule_interval
    )

oracle_opr = OracleOperator(
    task_id='task_sql',
    oracle_conn_id='oracle_connection',
    sql= 'select * from temp_table',
    autocommit ='True',
    dag=dag_gtb)


oracle_opr
```

***The Error:***

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: 
No such file or directory". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for hel
```

Comment: Try installing the [cx_Oracle](https://pypi.org/project/cx-Oracle/) and [Oracle operator](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-oracle/) in the Composer environment. See https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-package

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be:

Download the 64-bit version of oracle [instantClient](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html).

- Copy the Dll files from the instantClient directory to the Python directory.

[image]

If you haven’t installed cx_Oracle, you can run this command:

```
python -m pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade
```

Additionally, you can execute these commands to verify if everything is installed.

```
import sqlalchemy as sqla
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
 
# Test to see if it will print the version of sqlalchemy
print(sqla.__version__)    
 
# Test to see if the cx_Oracle is recognized
print(cx_Oracle.version)   
 
# This fails, but this will change after the solution
cx_Oracle.clientversion()
```

To see more documentation about cx_Oracle, please go [here](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Also, you can execute these commands to change the path of the oracle client files.

```
import os
import platform
 
# This is the path to the ORACLE client files
lib_dir = r"C:\put_your_path_here\instantclient-basic-windows.x64- 19.9.0.0.0dbru\instantclient_19_9"
 
# Diagnostic output to verify 64 bit arch and list files
print("ARCH:", platform.architecture())
print("FILES AT lib_dir:")
for name in os.listdir(lib_dir):
    print(name)
```

If you have the correct path, you should see a listing of all the Oracle files like: (adrci.exe, oci.dll, oci.sym, etc).

If you have the correct path, you should see the Oracle files like “adrci.exe, oci.dll, oci.sym….”. This is the location that Python needs to be able to find the Oracle drivers.

You can execute this code without errors.

```
# This fails, but this will change after the solution
cx_Oracle.clientversion()
```

Comment: **Please note that I did not do these operations on my local computer.**

How can I do this on cloud composer?

Comment: @tarik you can execute this code "python -m pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade" on the server side.